# Is there any way attacker could use mkdir to compromise a system?

Tags: security, directory

I'm setting up a restricted user account for user `ricardo`, a troublesome user on my system. I want to grant him the right to make directories using `sudo`, which he sometimes needs to do. I'm considering this rule in my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
ricardo   ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir
```

Using only this rule, is there any way ricardo could intentionally or accidentally compromise the system?

Comment: If you have a filesystem with a static inode count, he could use up all your inodes.

Comment: @jordanm The system uses an ext4 file system, which does have a static inode count, I believe.

Comment: In what ways is this user troublesome?

Comment: @schaiba He likes to tinker and see if he can exploit the system and doesn't always read the man pages as much as he should.

Comment: A proper user education, combined with no sudo at the time being, would be the recommended thing to do from me.

Comment: As @schaiba says, you can use such users by teaching them, and giving them responsibilities (under close supervision). I've seen wars between sysdamins and users, as the first ones tried to lock down the system too much. The users outnumbered the sysadmins 10 to 1, and even then (_without_ today's Internet access!) the defeat of the sysdamins was humiliating. _Never_ get into such a position!

Comment: That's the case of one ricardo too many. Or at least, thus spake BOFH...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suspect an attack like this would work, where «something» is a kernel module that will try to load after rootfs is mounted:

```
$ sudo mkdir -m 777 /lib/modules/`uname -r`/a
$ cp evil.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/a/«something».ko
```

Note also that you could use other names, depending on the aliases declared in the module. I'm guessing it won't get loaded until depmod is run, which will happen the next time there is a kernel update—so the `mkdir` won't even show recently in the sudo log.

There are lots of things in /etc that read all files in a directory, sometimes recursively. Even worse, some of those directories don't exist by default, and the only way to know about them is to read the manpage, init scripts, etc. for the program that uses them. Some, even worse, are deprecated backwards-compatibility things, and may not even be documented anymore.

**edit:** Thought of a few more directories, these in `/usr/local`:

- `/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2` (differs depending on Perl version, try `perl -V` to find out). Create a `File` subdirectory in there, and put a `Find.pm` in it. Now whenever anyone uses `File::Find`, they'll be using the attacker's version. Similarly, do the same with `Getopt::Long`. System utilities are often written in Perl, so this probably gives root. (Try `ack-grep --color -a 'use.+::' /usr/sbin | less -R`)
- I think Python, Ruby, etc. have similar directories. System utilities are written in Python as well.
- Subvert many things someone compiles with subdirectories of `/usr/local/include`.

Comment: Oh, but if <evil user> can copy modules to where the kernel will load them, the game is over before the start.

Comment: @vonbrand <evil user> normally can't, but used his `sudo mkdir` to create a new directory where he can.

Answer (score 20):

By running `mkdir` as root, the user can block other processes/users from creating new files and directories by creating directories with identical names (and/or wrong rights) before.

This could be security relevant especially with log- and [lock-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockfile#Lock_files)files.

As [jordanm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13796/jordanm) noted, the maximal number of [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) can be also used up
which can block the whole system.

By adding the user to specific groups (or using [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list#Filesystem_ACLs)), you should be able to solve the issues without granting any rights via `sudo`.

Comment: Great points. I'll probably leave `mkdir` off the list of commands ricardo is allowed to use.

Comment: If it is for exhausting inodes, a simple `for((i = 0;; i++)); do touch $i; done` will do fine (bashism, sorry; but you get the idea).

Comment: @vonbrand Except that's not as root, so it'll be stopped by a quota. Of course, other `sudo` commands OP is considering may allow exhausting inodes as well; OP needs to be aware of that DoS vector.

Answer (score 11):

You should redirect him to a chroot jail. Or even better, to a little VM, that he can crash once an hour. All you need to do is provide a new copy.

Comment: I highly recommend this.  Give him root access on his own VM.

Comment: to a chroot^H^H^H^H^Hounty jail...

Answer (score 6):

There's possibilities due to being able to create directories with write access. With `mkdir -m 777 blah` the `ricardo` user can write whatever they like into the new directory. You would need a process on the system already running as a different user that will recurse down a directory tree to load config, scripts or modules. Then the user could possibly add their own things to be loaded or run. The first thing I can think of is if you run a web server that can execute php or cgi. You could then run scripts as that user. I'm struggling to come up with more real world example's, especially `root` ones but I'm sure they are about.

ssh is an example of a daemon that traps this kind of scenario. If you created a `.ssh` directory for a user that didn't have one and put your own `authorized_hosts` file in place. `sshd` notices that the directories permissions are too open and ignores the public key.

You could definitely make a nuisance of yourself creating directories where files are expected to turn up (like transient tmp or swap files) which lots of programs would not handle nicely.

You could create lots of cgroups but it doesn't look you do anything with them. You might be able to bring a system to it's knees at least. It took about 10000 cgroups on a box with 256M for the [OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) to take out sshd.

If you control the `-m` option to `mkdir` and the UMASK of the `sudo` environment I think it's back to just being a nuisance.