# Is it okay to disable requiretty?

Tags: security, sudo, tty

I'm trying to set up a deploy script using [Capistrano](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html)  At a step `cap deploy:setup` script is connecting to my server and trying to run commands that create directories. Then I see an error: `msudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

There is a suggested solution to disable requiretty on my server. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49078/26271

I'm wondering if it is safe to do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a very limited security advantage in having `requiretty` on a server. If some non-root code is exploited (a PHP script, for example), the `requiretty` option means that the exploit code won't be able to directly upgrade its privileges by running `sudo`.

There may be another way for the attacker to gain root, and of course the attacker will still be able to deface your site, but not letting the attacker gain root means that other services running as different users will keep running normally and the attacker won't be able to erase system logs. If none of your `sudo` rules do [anything dangerous like creating a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65646/is-there-any-way-attacker-could-use-mkdir-to-compromise-a-system), this isn't a concern.

Furthermore — and more damning for `requiretty` — no privilege is needed to create a tty, e.g. with [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). So you might as well turn off `requiretty`: on its own, it does not provide a security advantage. It does provide a mild auditability advantage when executed by users (because the logs give a better idea of who invoked `sudo` and where they're coming from), but not when executed from a background job.

Comment: Do you mean that if the user can run `expect` (or `screen` for example), then `requiretty` is useless from a security point of view? (I didn't quite understand what you meant by "damning" in that sentence)

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron Yes, that's it. Since anyone can create a tty, the `requiretty` option doesn't prevent anyone from using sudo.

Comment: `requiretty` can prevent a user from leaking their password in cleartext, if they are executing a sudo command which requires a password via ssh. It's there to force the user to call ssh -t.

Comment: @Chris Betti -- why is that a good thing, to enforce ssh -t ... ?

Comment: My thinking at the time was that in this case, if you are executing a remote sudo command that prompts for a password, then it is better to leverage the remote machine's askpass program than to fill the password in cleartext via the console. I honestly have no idea if doing so provides enhanced security, other than possibly preventing the situation where your password is echoed to the screen as you type it. I believe I was thinking that an askpass program would not be invoked without a tty or pseudo-tty.