# How to set up a script to run as root non-interactively?

Tags: permissions, root, non-root-user, setuid

I need to set up the following script to run *as root* whenever I log in:

```
#!/bin/zsh
truncate -s 0 ~yourstruly/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc.log
```

I know how to run the script as root interactively (namely through `sudo`), but I can't figure out how to make the script run as root *non-interactively* whenever I log in.

How can I do this?

FWIW: the script is currently owned by root, has permissions 6755, and the file to be truncated is also owned by root and has permissions 0644, but when I run the script, the call to `truncate` fails with a "Permission denied" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions of the script are irrelevant. [Setuid and setgid bits are ignored on scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts) on Linux and most other unices.

You can configure sudo to allow you to run this script without specifying a password, with the `NOPASSWD` tag. Make sure that `sudo` doesn't require to be connected to a terminal: [turn off the `requiretty` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65774/is-it-okay-to-disable-requiretty). Note that the `NOPASSWD`-tagged rule must come before any other rule that would let you run the command with a password prompt, because the first match applies. So run `visudo`:

```
Defaults !requiretty
kjo ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/nc-logs-truncate
kjo ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Change the first line of the script to `#!/bin/zsh -f`, otherwise zsh will load `~/.zshenv` which isn't desirable here.

Now that I've answered your literal question, this is probably not the best method. A simple `chown kjo ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc.log` would ensure that the log file belongs to you so you can truncate it at will.

Better, move the log file instead of truncating it: it's often useful to keep recent logs around (for example to compare working logs to non-working logs if nc fails). Give yourself write permission on the directory (you might own it already) and

```
mv -f ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc.log ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc.log.0
touch ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect/ncsvc.log
```

Alternatively, make a more unixy NC package, tell `ncsvc` to write its logs in `/var/log`, and include its log in the `logrotate` configuration.