# Run a sudo (or startup) python script from cron on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sudo, cron, python, startup, raspberry-pi

I'm helping out with an art project (http://stargateeggbeater.com/ for those interested) built on Raspberry Pi. The RPi controls an addressable LED strip through the GPIO, using the `spidev` device per these [instructions](http://www.brianhensley.net/2012/07/getting-spi-working-on-raspberry-pi.html). To start the display, we run:

```
sudo python lightpaint-FF.py
```

We plan to take this project to parties and festivals, so ideally we'd like to have it start running automatically on boot. (Our RPi doesn't have a monitor connected, so right now we have to log in with another laptop using SSH and run the code using `nohup` before logging out again).

My first attempt at solving this problem was to write a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! "$(pidof python)" ] 
 then
   sudo python /home/pi/lightpaint-FF.py
fi
```

And to modify `/etc/crontab` to include

```
* * * * * root /home/pi/EggbeaterCronJob
```

The desired behavior is to check every minute to see if any Python instances are running and, if not, start the python script. I have verified that this script works when called from a terminal:

```
pidof python # returns nothing
sudo /home/pi/EggbeaterCronJob
pidof python # returns new process ID
```

But after updating my `crontab`, no python process ID ever appears on its own accord. Just to be sure, I also made sure I wasn't making a boneheaded mistake in my `crontab` configuration:

```
* * * * * root touch test-freaking-cron
```

This verified that `cron` was indeed responding to my edits.

Comment: What distro are you running on your Pi?

Comment: While I guess the cron job should work, it might be more straightforward to just use an infinite loop in the bash script with `sleep 60` at the end.  Also makes it easier to stop ;).  Very very cool, that LED strip light painting stuff!

Comment: And then put that in /etc/rc.local

Comment: why don't you write a service file? it depends on what distribution you're using but that seems easier than using cron.

Comment: strugee, thanks. I was able to get some advice from friends and waded through the thick documentation for update-rc.d.  IMHO the task of making sense of the dense SysV documentation is harder than a cron job (for a beginner!) :-)  But in terms of functionality, yes, I agree with you that starting the program on startup makes more sense than running a redundant script every minute. (The cron option would have the advantage of auto-restarting the python code if it were to break---but we've already used this toy for several hours at a time with no problem, so hopefully that won't be needed!)

Comment: For future Googlers, for the record, I did not figure out why the Cron script didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `sudo` its not needed since its running as root, and sudo by default wont run without a tty.

You can tell sudo to run without a tty by running `visudo` and commenting out requiretty:

`#Default requiretty`

NOTE this does have security disadvantages see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65774/is-it-okay-to-disable-requiretty)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start a program at boot time, the easiest way on most setups is to add a command to `/etc/rc.local`. If the file exists, add this line to it:

```
python /path/to/lightpaint-FF.py &
```

If the file doesn't exist, try creating it with the content

```
#!/bin/sh
python /path/to/lightpaint-FF.py &
exit 0
```

A few embedded distributions don't support `/etc/rc.local`. If the one you're using doesn't, tell us what it is.

---

If you need to monitor the program and relaunch it if it dies, you can do it through `init`. How to do it depends on which init your distribution uses.

- For a traditional init, add a line to [`/etc/inittab`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=inittab&sektion=5). BusyBox can support inittab but it's an optional feature that needs to be selected at compile time.

  ```
  lp:2345:respawn:/usr/in/python /path/to/lightpaint-FF.py
  ```
- For upstart, write an upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html).